# PyQt: how to create a dialog as a child of another dialog

Tags: dialog, pyqt, parent-child

In PyQt, I have a dialog that spawns another dialog (when you click a button to do so in the first dialog).  I want to maintain a strong parent-child relationship, for garbage collection purposes, and to make the .findChild and .findChildren functions usable.

The root of the question may be: how do you use .setParent() but still have the object in question be shown as a separate window, rather than shown within the parent widget?

The 'parent' dialog (actually a container widget within a tab within a dialog) is 'newEntryWidget'.  It spawns 'clueDialog' when a signal (not shown here) calls newEntryWidget.quickTextClueAction as a slot.  Visually, clueDialog should be a "top level window" with its own banner, its own window attributes (I want to keep it on top of everything else), etc.

```
class newEntryWidget(QWidget,Ui_newEntryWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent,sec=0,formattedLocString='',fleet='',dev='',origLocString='',amendFlag=False,amendRow=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.parent=parent # just an attribute; not the same as setParent
...
...
    def quickTextClueAction(self):
            self.newClueDialog=clueDialog(self,self.ui.timeField.text(),self.ui.teamField.text(),self.ui.radioLocField.text(),lastClueNumber+1)
            self.newClueDialog.show()


class clueDialog(QDialog,Ui_clueDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent,t,callsign,radioLoc,newClueNumber):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.parent=parent # just an attribute; not the same as setParent
...
...
```

Right now, since I am using self.parent=parent, which is just an attribute and not true "parent/child relationship" in Qt terms, clueDialog does display as a top level window, which is what I want:

[image]

But, if I add 'self.setParent(parent)' in the clueDialog **init** function, I get this:

[image]

How can I preserve the top-level-window behavior, and have the real-honest-parent-child-relationship so that .findChild(clueDialog) will work from within the newEntryWidget object?

Ultimately, I want to enforce that the newEntryWidget object should not be closed if it still has and 'child' clueDialogs open.

Comment: If you display newClueDialog modally using `exec_` instead of `show`, it will display with its own window frame and also disable newEntryWidget so that it can't be closed before he clue dialog.  But I don't know if you want to disable newEntryWidget altogether?

Comment: Hadn't really thought about it, but, clueDialog should probably not be modal / blocking.

Comment: When you modelessly `show` newClueDialog, doesn't it have its own window frame, caption bar, etc and can't you move it outside of the parent by dragging its caption bar?  It's not like it's a child permanently bound within the newEntryWidger is it?  It's original position is centered over the parent window but you should be able to drag it off and programmatically move it.

Comment: Yes it is strange.  Updated the question to illustrate.

Comment: Instead of calling setParent(), call `QDialog.__init__(self, parent)` which constructs the clue dialog with a parent from the beginning.

Comment: Isn't that already done with self.newClueDialog=clueDialog(self,self.ui.timeField.text(),self.ui.teamField.text(),self.ui.radioLocField.text(),lastClueNumber+1)  (or, if I had no custom arguments, self.newClueDialog=clueDialog(self)?  However, is that first argument in init really used as anything other than a simple data attribute?

Comment: `self.newClueDialog = clueDialog(self, ...)` specifies the parent, but in your override of `__init__` you choose what to do with it.  I suggest you pass it to the `QDialog.__init` so that Qt establishes the parent-child relationship at the beginning of `clueDialog`s lifetime.  Setting it this way allows Qt to do things like destroy `clue` if you close the parent `newEntry`.

Comment: oh I see what you mean.  Bingo - that did it.  Now when I do findchildren(QDialog) from the closeEvent of the parent newEntryDialog, it does show up:  children:[<__main__.clueDialog object at 0x069878F0>]  Thanks!  If you want to post as an answer in the next day or so then I'll accept it, otherwise after a day I'll post an answer with credit to your comments and self-accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `.setParent`, call `QDialog.__init__(self, parent)` which constructs the clue dialog with a parent from the beginning. Setting it this way allows Qt establishes the parent-child relationship at the beginning of `clueDialog`'s lifetime.

I believe this will fix both your issues:  1) the `clue` window frame, caption, etc. will be painted, 2) you will be able to iterate for proper children of `newEntry`.

Comment: Thanks for the help per comments in the original question, this did the trick.